# Ctrl+ Space not giving proposals in Java Files?

Tags: android, eclipse-adt

Ctrl+Space is not giving any proposals in Java Files.
It is working fine in XML files.
I have updated my ADT tools, still problem persists.

Comment: Ctrl+C copies to clipboard.

Comment: sorry buddy.. i meant Ctrl+Space

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click `Preferences>Java>Editor>Content Assist>Advanced` and make sure that both instances of `Java Proposals` are checked. Strangely, this happened to me today. (I think this is answered elsewhere. I'll try to find the SO link.)